# Dynamically generating id's for div using functions

Tags: javascript

I want to generate id's for input field of div's dynamically using functions.

Comment: mentioning what all you have tried is always helpful in understanding what exactly you want.

Comment: Have you made any attempt(s) of doing this yourself? If so can you edit your question and show your attempt(s) and maybe someone can explain why your attempt isn't working and offer a solution. Thanks.

Comment: you can always use LOOPING. Can you describe more or have a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want at least 2 functions it looks like constructor function producing nested "next" function would satisfy requirement:

```
function idGenerator(baseId) {
   var current = 1;
   function nextId() {
      return "" + baseId + current++;
   }
   return nextId;
}

// usage 
var generator = idGenerator("dynamicId");
console.log(generator()); // prints dynamicId1
console.log(generator()); // prints dynamicId2...
console.log(generator());

// create div with jQuery and new Id:
var myDiv = $("<div></div>").attr("id", generator());
```

Comment: how to call this function directly i.e example <input type="text" id="idGenerator()">

Comment: @user3484775 It totally depends on how you actually generating that HTML (i.e. with some templating engine like KnockoutJS or Handlebars you can call functions from template). Side note: you probably should ask separate more specific question on what you actually trying to achieve along with a sample...